# supposer que - indicative or subjunctive

Tags: verbes, subjonctif, indicatif

Should I use the subjunctive mood or the indicative mood with the verb "supposer"? Examples:

- Je suppose qu'il fait/fasse toujours ça. (= I assume that he always do that)
- Supposons qu'elle est/soit coupable. (= Let's assume that she is guilty)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When *supposer* is followed by a dependent clause beginning with *que*, the verb in the dependent clause may be in the subjunctive mood or in the indicative mood depending on what *supposer* expresses.

When it expresses an **assumption** we use the **indicative**:

- Je suppose que tu as envie d'aller jouer avec tes copains alors dépêche-toi de finir tes devoirs.
- Il a encore laissé la porte du jardin ouverte, je suppose qu'il fait toujours ça.

When it expresses an **hypothesis** we use the **subjunctive**. This is the case with : *En supposant que*, *supposé que*, *à supposer que*, *supposons que*:

- En supposant que tu aies fini tes devoirs avant le dîner, tu pourras rejoindre tes copains quand tu auras fini de manger.
- À supposer qu'il fasse beau demain, nous pourrons aller à la plage.
- Supposons qu'il soit coupable, n'aurait-il pas déjà pu envisager cette situation pour pouvoir maitriser sa réaction ?
  ([Source](http://www.lefigaro.fr/actualite-france/2010/03/17/01016-20100317ARTFIG00420-l-emploi-du-temps-de-viguier-et-de-durandet-dans-le-detail-.php))

Comment: But then what is the difference between an **assumption** and an **hypothesis**? Their meanings are virtually the same and it then doesn't seem enough of a clear-cut to decide on the mood. Or did you mean "assertion" instead of "assumption"?

Comment: @TheQuark  The degree of certainty is different, hence the difference in the tense used. An assumption (*supposition*) is when we assume something to be true. A hypothesis (*hypothèse*) is when we imagine something could be true. To put it simply, of course, science & philosophy would deal with those at length. No, I did not mean assertion, you can't really suppose something that you assert.

Answer (score 1):

**I**

There exists a first sense for which the indicative is correct ([A 1. b](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/supposer)). The verb means "to accept as true, as probable".

> b) [Le compl. d'obj. est une complét. introd. par que] Considérer quelque chose comme probable; poser quelque chose comme hypothèse.
>   [Le verbe de la sub. est à l'ind. indiquant la certitude de l'assertion] **Admettre comme certain (ce qui va suivre)**.
>    (user **LPH**'s bold type)

- Je suppose que vous revenez par Dieppe. (FLAUB., Corresp., 1871, p. 283) (...)
- Vous savez sans doute qui je suis? Non, mais je suppose que vous appartenez à la police. Commissaire Maigret... Enchantée. (SIMENON, Vac. Maigret, 1948, p. 158)

*More examples from the literature*

- … mais je suppose que les circonstances étant telles, le Gouvernement sera amené à penser, et j'espère qu'il en sera ainsi , qu'il faut user de cette possibilité qui sera ...
- Je suppose que Dieu, qui rend toutes les autres âmes immortelles, finira la durée de la mienne au moment de ma mort;
- Je suppose que tu as raison : je m'y habituerai.
- Maintenant je suppose que les particules constituantes du fluide nerveux ou de l'esprit animal, ne sont pas toutes exactement semblables: qu'il en est de différentes grosseurs
- Je suppose que je ne peux m'y opposer dans la mesure où cet animal n'habite plus ici
- … tu supposes que sa naissance est le fruit du hasard et non d'un artisan possédant un pouvoir et une connaissance exceptionnels

As the meaning of "assume" is taken to be "to take for granted"  one should always say "Je suppose qu'il fait toujours ça.". However, "Je suppose qu'il fasse toujours ça." is a correct grammatical possibility; you just can't take "to assume" to mean "to take for granted" any more and you must use the meaning "suppose for the sake of argument" that "to assume" also has.

**II**

There is a second sense ([A 1. b](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/supposer)), connected to the preceding,  for which the subjunctive must be used. The meaning is that of strict supposition, that of stating a hypothesis.

> b) [Le compl. d'obj. est une complét. introd. par que] Considérer quelque chose comme probable; poser quelque chose comme hypothèse.
>   [Le verbe de la sub. est au subj., empl. pour un tour hyp.] **Émettre une hypothèse**
>   (user **LPH**'s bold type)

- Supposons que trahir devienne une devise. (HUGO, Légende, t. 5, 1877, p. 1093)
- Monsieur: Vous me connaissez? Jean: Non, monsieur, du tout! Monsieur: Alors, qu'est-ce qui vous fait supposer que je sois l'homme que je suis. Jean: Heu... rien! ou plutôt, ce qui revient au même, tout!.  (GUITRY, Veilleur, 1911, II, p. 16)

*More examples from the literature (also mathematics, science)*

- … supposons qu'étranger, sans ami dans notre ville, vous ne puissiez y trouver le moyen de ...
- Portons donc CD sur AB autant de fois que possible, et supposons qu'on ait AB = 3CD + EB
- … supposons qu'ils viennent s'offrir ...
- Supposons... qu'en parallèle, la technologie de la robotique subisse de la même façon une accélération de type fractal
- Supposons qu'il ne se soit pas vu d'abord dans la Cigogne, qu'il ait cru facile de la tromper
- Ainsi, par exemple, supposons qu'il s'agisse de multiplier a' par a' : le produit sera as
- Supposons qu'on ait à sa disposition une lunette astronomique munie d'un double prisme,

*Exceptions*¹

- Supposons qu'il doit, d'après la norme existante du profit, en tirer 20 °/o
- Supposons qu'aucune de ces deux chaînes n'est triviale, et soit w (resp. u') le premier mot de la chaîne de u à v (resp. v') : on u —»o w —»# v et u —og w' —», v'.
- Supposons qu'il est différent celui qu'on vient d'observer ; (1831)
- Supposons qu'il était dans l'état 1. Alors Edward était dans le même état. S'il n'avait pas changé d'état entre les deux affirmations,
- Allons plus loin, Messieurs, supposons pour un instant que la responsabilité médicale est écrite dans la loi; supposons qu'un médecin ou un chirurgien peut être mis en accusation par cause d'impéritie;
- Point du tout: supposons qu'il y aurait parmis tous ces concurrens deux ou trois artistes à qui il faudrait plus de tems qu'aux autres, (**conditionnel**)

In this context of pure hypothesis one finds often the form "supposons" or "supposez" and "supposes" (imperative) but "supposer" in the indicative is also possible. So, one should never say "Supposons qu'elle est coupable." if this is "supposer" in the sense of "assuming for the sake of argument". However, as can been seen from the examples, the exceptions made by the writers, faulty uses should we say, are not so rare.

¹<sub>The number of examples as compared to that in the preceding set of examples is not representative of the proportion of exceptions, which is quite low.</sub>